# How can one check the blocks found on PPLNS pool, such as xmrpool.net?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, mining-pools

I've been mining to xmrpool.net for a few months now.  Their dashboard has had a couple of bugs but has otherwise been good.  It used to average about 2 blocks found per day and now nothing for 6 days as reported by https://xmrpool.net/#/blocks.  Is there any way for me to independently confirm that the pool is still working and that's it's simply some kind of parse error on the site?  Thanks.